# PHP Background cron job

Tags: php, cron

A script has an execution time of more than a minute. So, therefore I would like to run the script as a background task.

I've read a lot about it on the internet and read that `print shell_exec('/usr/bin/php -q page.php &');` isn't the solution since the taks is still a child of the process. I've tested it with sleep(10) and indeed, the page which should call the cron job is waiting for 10 seconds.

So, symcbean have written an article ( http://symcbean.blogspot.nl/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html?m=1 ) and is suggesting the following code:

```
print `echo /usr/bin/php -q longThing.php | at now`;
```

But, unfortunately, i script didn't do anything and after adding `2>&1` I get the following response:

> sh: at: command not found

I've search a lot for solving this issue, but can't find any solution.

Comment: The title mentions a cron job, but have this has nothing to do with it?

Comment: `crontab` is for running a program on a regular schedule, such as every day, every hour, etc. Is that what you want?

Comment: You both guys are correct, it isn't a regular schedule. I just would like to run a background task instead of a schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the fully qualified path to the `at` command for example `/bin/at`.

If you're not sure of the path you can usually type `which at` at the command line to find the path to the command.

Comment: Oké, sounds clear. So I should find it via the command line, but unfortunately I can't do it right now. Suppose that the pad is /bin/at, the new script is then:
print `echo /usr/bin/php -q longThing.php | /bin/at now`;

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: I had to install the at command and now the at command is oké, but get another error: sh: now: command not found

Comment: Somehow the `now` argument to `at` is being interpreted as a command. Perhaps try running getting the shell command working from the command line before you try launching it in PHP.